# Call generic method from generic method with exact same where clause requires cast?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

*Can't imagine this isn't a dupe but I can't seem find any previously matching questions.*

I have a generic method

```
public T GetSetting<T>(Guid userId) where T : ISetting, new()
```

This in it's turn calls a generic method

```
public static ISetting CreateSetting<T>(IDictionary<string, object> data) where T:ISetting, new()
```

The signatures of T are exactly the same, yet the compiler requires me to cast the value like so:

```
return (T) BaseSetting.CreateSetting<T>(data);
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a limitation of the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is returning the type ISetting. While a T reference is always an ISetting reference, an ISetting reference doesn't have to be a T reference. That is why you have to cast it.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of CreateSetting only states that it returns an ISetting. It doesn't require that that ISetting has to be of type T.

If you change the signature to

```
public static T CreateSetting<T>(IDictionary<string, object> data) where T:ISetting, new()
```

it will work without casting.